# How to list all references to bookmarks used in the document

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to show all locations where a bookmark link is inserted into a Google Doc?  Ideally, it would list all bookmark references in all documents I use in my Google Drive, not just the current document.

Note that I'm not talking about inserting bookmarks, but only finding locations where they exist.

I would like this to work within the browser, and not have to export it into some other format that I have to use offline and do searching there (which I know I can figure out how to do, but it is a hassle).